# How to perform action after all parallel queries are successful in "React-Query"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

In React-Query we can use the useQueries hook to perform parallel queries (mostly like using Promise.all): https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/parallel-queries

Every Query has a set of options that we can use, on of them is the `onSuccess` and can be used as below:

```
const data = useQueries([{
    queryKey: 1,
    queryFn: () => axios.get(...),
    onSuccess: data => ... do something,
  },
  {
    queryKey: 2,
    queryFn: () => axios.get(...),
    onSuccess: data => ... do something,
  },
])
```

But what I really need is to be able to perform an action only when all the queries all successful. Mostly like:

```
Promise.all(fn).then(...)
```

and use that data to run a function afterwards.

I came up with a few things like

**1** - pushing all the successful queries to a `useState()`

```
onSuccess: (data) => setData((prevData) => [...prevData, data])
```

and setup a useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
// run function
}, [data])
```

But this won't work because it will fire every time one of the queries is successful. Probably will break due to an infinite loop.

**2** - Making a condition for when all are successful:

```
 if (data.every(num => num.isSuccess === true)) {
    // do something
  }
```

This might work but it looks clumsy to me. Wondering if theres a better and more performant method out there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Wondering if theres a better and more performant method out there.

I don't think there is. `useQueries` is very generic and unopinionated. For some use-cases, it makes sense to show e.g. a loading spinner until all requests are finished, and for others it make more sense to show data as soon as one request is finished. That's why checking with `data.every` or `data.some` seems like a good idea.

For rendering things, this is rather easy, for actual side-effects, there is no callback specifically for that, so I think you'd need:

```
const allSuccess = data.every(num => num.isSuccess === true)

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (allSuccess) {
    // do your side-effect here
  }
}, [allSuccess])
```

Depending on your use-case, it might make more sense to check for `data !== undefined` instead of isSuccess. If a background refetch fails, the query will go to `error` state, but it will still have (stale) data in the cache. So to only run the effect "once" when everything completes, I would do this:

```
const allSuccess = data.every(num => num.data !== undefined)
```

Comment: What if data has changed due to refetch?

Comment: not sure what you mean with that question? if a refetch changes data, it updates the screen?